# How to run a python file on codalab?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to submit to a competition hosted on Codalab.

I am using codalab/default-gpu:latest docker image

I have uploaded a simple file with the following contents

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

and trying to run this file using

`run --request-docker-image codalab/default-gpu:latest --request-memory 4g "python3 imports.py"`

But everytime I am getting `python3: can't open file 'imports.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Can anyone help me here??

EDIT : using `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` docker image now

Comment: Not clear how your code gets into the container. If you look at [the image here](https://worksheets.codalab.org/), notice the `:src` and `src/train.py`

Comment: @OneCricketeer So, I have to put it in a folder for it to run? Can't I just write `run :imports.py "python3 imports.py" `

Comment: @OneCricketeer I uploaded the file again but this time inside a folde `src`, and I ran `run :src "python3 src/imports.py"`, and it worked. The command in the above line also worked. Thanks. You can post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Because the default filepath is not `/src` and the file might not have been uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

From Comments

> User has uploaded the file inside a folder `src`, and he ran `run :src "python3 src/imports.py"`,and it worked.(paraphrased from OneCricketeer)